# React Native ellipsizeMode - 2 Text in same line

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I want to implement something like this

case 1: if text is longer than screen width

```
+--------------------------------------+
| very long teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.. (1234)|
+--------------------------------------+
```

case 2: if text is not longer than screen width

```
+--------------------------------------+
| short text (1234)                    |
+--------------------------------------+
```

but right now I always get result like this:

case 1: OK, first text in ellipse and 1234 next to it

```
+--------------------------------------+
| very long teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.. (1234)|
+--------------------------------------+
```

case 2:not OK, the 1234 text is in very right of screen

```
+--------------------------------------+
| short text                     (1234)|
+--------------------------------------+
```

this is my code right now:

```
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text
        style={[styles.placeNameStyles, { flex: 1 }]}
        numberOfLines={1}
        ellipsizeMode='tail'
        onPress={() => this.props.onPlaceNamePress()}
      >
        {this.props.text}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.distanceStyles}>
          (1234)
      </Text>
    </View>
```

if I remove `flex: 1` from first text I got something like this:

case 1: not OK, 1234 text is off the screen

```
+--------------------------------------+
| very long teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee..|
+--------------------------------------+
```

case 2:OK, now 1234 right next to first text

```
+--------------------------------------+
| short text (1234)                    |
+--------------------------------------+
```

so my question is how I implement something like my first example (1234 text is in right next to first text)?

Answer (score 3):

try to set flexShrink to first Text style?

```
<Text
   style={{
     ...otherStyles,
     flexShrink: 2
   }}
/>
```